# AngularJS Scroll to Bottom after Scope Change/resource Change

Tags: angularjs

Currently I tried to make it with [$anchorScroll](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24anchorScroll)

But I don't know where to place the

```
<a id="bottom">
```

currently my view is a 
`<table>` and i have a `ng-repeat` on a `<tr>`.
Then I `$watch` for scope changes and apply them to the `ng-repeat`.

html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="document in documents.items">
    <td>{{document.subject}}</td>
    <td>{{document.course}}</td>
    <td>{{document.bundle}}</td>
    <td>{{document.lesson}}</td>
    <td>{{document.category}}</td>
    <td>{{document.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Code in my Controller:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('search', function (newData, oldData) {
    if (newData != null) {
        $scope.documents = Document.query(newData)
        console.log(newData);
    }
```

Now I tried to put the `$location.hash` and `$anchorScroll` after the `$scope.documents` but nothing ever happend.

Also a Bonus question:
Should I place a paging function to a `directive` or should i make it with `<div ng-click="nextPage()">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out that i just need a `setTimeout` due to the fact, that i first change the scope and then try to scroll to bottom, but the new scope isn't rendered yet!

**EDIT**:
To Scroll after content get's rendered via `ng-repeat`: do `setTimeout(() => { /* Your scroll stuff here */ }, 0);` to

Comment: Instead of using $timeout, which is pretty insecure (consider a slow connnection) you could return a promise, resolve it and only after it has been resolved successfully, do the scroll

Comment: no the resource gets loaded and i try to scroll after promise. but since i render the document with ng-repeat i need the setTimeout(function(){}, 0) to scroll after the ng-repeat.

Comment: @ChristianSchmitt, thanks, the 0ms timeout works perfectly. Yours is the first and only useful solution yet, after searching for about an hour.